# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 12

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting all files from storage and is working fine but shows this error. after adding zip code.I am getting all files from storage and is working fine but shows this error. after adding zip code

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 12
```

My code:

```
ListView.builder(
            //if file/folder list is grabbed, then show here
            itemCount: files?.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                title: Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf),
                trailing: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  var folderName = 'ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg.zip';
                  final sourceDir = Directory(files[index].path);
                  files = [
                    File(sourceDir.path + files[index].path),
                    File(sourceDir.path + files[index].path)
                  ];

                  final zipFile = File("storage/emulated/0/zip/${files[index].path.split('/').last}.zip");
                  try {
                    ZipFile.createFromFiles(
                        sourceDir: sourceDir, files: files, zipFile: zipFile);
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }



                  // Navigator.push(context,
                  //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  //   return ViewPDF(pathPDF: files[index].path.toString());
                  //   //open viewPDF page on click
                  // }
                  // ));
                },
              ));
            },
          )
```

Comment: could you add the full code of your ListView?

Comment: code addedddddd

Comment: could you include createFromFiles code too?

Comment: its package flutter archiever

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 12
```

is indicating that your list length is 2 i.e. 0 and 1, but you are trying to access value of 12th index, which not exists.

Comment: can you plz edit my code

Comment: Please share createFromFiles function.

Comment: im using package flutter archiever

Comment: Ok, So I think it cause issue when you are creating Files where both the paths are same.

Comment: can you help me with zipping files

Comment: try this files = [ File(sourceDir.path + files[index].path) ];

Comment: same error   RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 2

Comment: If you are using vscode try to add exceptional break point, it will show you exact line of code which cause this error

Comment: im using android studio

Comment: it only happens when i put  create a zip files from given list of files code from this package

Comment: package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_archive

Comment: now it shows file must be reside under rootDir